# Modular arithmetic with many variables

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose we know that
> $$\gcd\left(\frac{a_1\ell-bk}{d},d\right)=\gcd\left(\frac{a_2\ell-bk}{d},d\right)=f,\quad \gcd(k,\ell)=d .$$ Then it implies that $f\mid \dfrac{\ell}{d}(a_1-a_2)$.
> Since $\gcd(k,\ell)=d$, we see that $\gcd(\dfrac{\ell}{d},f)=1$. Hence
> $a_1\equiv a_2\pmod f$.

This is an excerpt from the paper which I am reading now. How it follows that $\gcd(\dfrac{\ell}{d},f)=1$? I have tried some ways to prove it but failed.

Can anyone show how to prove it please?
Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** I forgot to add that $\gcd(a_1,k)=\gcd(a_2,k)=\gcd(b,\ell)=1$.

Comment: what paper would that be?

Comment: @WillJagy, you can find it on page 8. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.13266.pdf.

Comment: It doesn't seem to follow to me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your clarification,

write $l=de$ and $k=dg$.

We have that $(e,g)=(b,e)=1$.

If a prime $p$ divided both $e$ and $f$,

then because $p$ would divide $a_1 e-bg$,

it would have to be that $p$ would divide either $b$ or $g$, which the conditions don't allow.

Comment: Sorry but why $\gcd (b,e)=1$? Did you mean $\gcd (b,\ell)=1$?

Comment: @ZFR if $b$ shares no prime factors with $de$, it shares no prime factors with $e$

Comment: Of course! When I started to write this on the paper it became clear! Thanks a lot for your answer! +1